# nodejs returns config and headers information

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

[image]

HI Why is my express is returning headers and config objects details, where as I am just returning the object data.

Comment: app.post("/userrecord",function(req,res){
 
 console.log(req.query.name);
 var userData = {
  name : req.query.name,
  designation : req.query.desig,
  town : req.query.town
 }
 var userR = new UserR(userData);
 userR.save(function(err){
  UserR.find({},function(error, data){
//   console.log(data);
   //res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   res.json(data);
  });
 
 });

});

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard response from a node server. This response contains headers information,status code and other additional information. You can edit these values in your express configuration. The actual data sent from the server is inside data property of response.